# Enhancing performance for responsive images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive page that I'm trying to optimize the page load time for. I ran the yslow extension on the page and on of the suggestions was inserting width and height attributes to the image so that it can render images before loading css: (example)

```
<img src="example.png" width="50px" height="50px" />
```

My question is, is there a way to implement something similar, but in a way that retains the responsive properties of the images on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set width and height of images in CSS file and adjust them using media queries.

Of you can set image as a background on its parent container:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

The background approach works very well with sprites, which is another way to speed up your page.